# C# WPF How to call Combobox from Method?

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, c#-4.0, wpf-controls

I need to call a Combobox SelectionChanged from a Method.

There are only 4 search results on Google, none work.

**Combobox**

```
private void ComboBox1_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    //actions
}
```

**Method**

In WinForms I used this, works fine:

```
MyMethod(){    
    //call combobox
    ComboBox1_SelectionChanged(sender, e);
}
```

In WPF I try:

```
MyMethod(){   
    //call combobox
    ComboBox1.RaiseEvent(new RoutedEventArgs(ComboBox.SelectionChangedEvent));
}
```

But it does not work.

Exception:Thrown: "Object of type 'System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs' cannot be converted to type 'System.Windows.Controls.SelectionChangedEventArgs'."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think WPF is the same with winform, you could also use winform's code to call "SelectionChanged" handler method like my following code:

```
private void ComboBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("called");
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.ComboBox_SelectionChanged(sender,null);
    }
```

Comment: Looks like it's working, thanks. ComboBox 1 activates through Method when ComboBox 2 or Button is pressed. https://i.imgur.com/flSqqE9.png

Comment: If my reply was helpful to you. You could mark it as answer.Thanks.